# Ghostscript with AES-256 password protection for PDF 2.0 documents

Tags: ghostscript

A password protected pdf file can be generated with ghostscript:

```
gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=protect.pdf -sOwnerPassword=pwd1 -sUserPassword=pwd2 -dCompatibilityLevel=2.0 test.pdf
```

The output file has the newest pdf version 2.0 which has unicode support for password protection. But according to pdfinfo the obsolete RC4 algorithm was used:

```
pdfinfo protect.pdf -upw pwd2
CreationDate: Sat Apr 21 09:10:14 2018 CEST
ModDate: Sat Apr 21 09:10:14 2018 CEST
Tagged: no
UserProperties: no
Suspects: no
Form: none
JavaScript: no
Pages: 26
Encrypted: yes (print:yes copy:yes change:yes addNotes:yes algorithm:RC4)
Page size: 612 x 792 pts (letter)
Page rot: 0
File size: 288060 bytes
Optimized: no
PDF version: 2.0
```

According to https://www.pdflib.com/knowledge-base/pdf-password-security/encryption/ the PDF 2.0 version is able to encrypt PDF files with the AES-256 standard. How can I do this with ghostscript?

Comment: Seems like you might be out of luck. This is the only relevant thread I could find, and according to comment #10, this was for decryption. https://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=690702#c10 Here's a page that explains how to use qpdf (another command-line tool) to add password restrictions to an existing file, so maybe that's good enough for you: https://rsmith.home.xs4all.nl/howto/pdf-tricks.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ghostscript pdfwrite device doesn't support anything except the original RC4 algorithm for **encrypting** PDF files. The PDF interpreter can **decrypt** documents using later algorithms.

So as sneep says, you can't do this with Ghostscript and the pdfwrite device.