# How to set a password for PDF file export?

Tags: vba, ms-access, pdf

I need to add a password for extracting PDF.

```vb
Dim FileName As String
Dim FilePath As String
FileName = Me.Full_Name & "_" & Me.ID
FilePath = "C:\Users\Desktop\" & FileName & ".Pdf"
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "Report", acFormatPDF, FilePath
MsgBox "Exported Successfully"
```

Comment: I don't think that this can be done using `DoCmd.OutputTo`, and I think that you may need to use a third party PDF writer to do this.

Comment: PDF files can be manipulated with VBA. There is a reference library. However, in my experience, requires a version of Adobe Acrobat (not the Reader) to be installed as well.

Comment: Hi Applecore - This code working fine exporting the report in PDF. i need to set a password for exporting PDF's if any can help me on this!

Comment: Regular PDF document viewer does not support passwords - you  require a higher paid version. Output of PDF from Access does not support passwords. You could output the file, and then open with PDF (adobe), set a password and close it. And you could do this 2nd step of open with PDF + set password in VBA code, but you need a paid version of adobe acrobat to do this. The free edition does not allow nor have a password option - you need some kind of paid version for this feature. All versions of PDF support opening a PDF and asking for a password, but only paid versions allow setting of password.

Comment: Like Albert said, you'll need a third party solution. How about exporting a pdf and zipping it afterwards using a password? You could use 7-zip and a command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using Ghostscript. First print your pdf like you already do, then call the function below. Ghostscript is free under license agreement, afaik.

```
Public Function fctPDO_Print_pdf_GhostScript(strFile_for_pdf As String, Optional strUserPassword As String = "", Optional strOwnerPassword As String = "") As String

        ' http://www.herber.de/forum/archiv/1164to1168/1165503_Zusammenfuehren_von_PDF_Files.html#1165503
        ' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49953421/ghostscript-with-aes-256-password-protection-for-pdf-2-0-documents

        ' PDO: Prints a pdf (originally multi-pdf). Requires Ghostscript, and read/write rights.
        '      Existing files are overwritten without asking.
        '      Provide both passwords to lock. Ghostscript does rc4 , being comparatively unsafe.
        '

          On Error Resume Next

          Dim fso As Object, WshShell As Object
          Dim strZielOrdner As String
          Dim strQuellOrdner As String
          Dim strCommand As String
          Dim strGhostScript As String

          Dim strFile_with_Path As String
          Dim strTargetFile_without_Path As String



          Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

         'Path to gswin32c.exe
          strGhostScript = "C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs9.19\bin\gswin32c.exe"

         ' Define folder

          strQuellOrdner = "D:\PDO_test"
          strZielOrdner = "D:\PDO_test"


         ' Shell-command prepare
          strZielOrdner = fso.GetFolder(strZielOrdner).ShortPath
          strGhostScript = fso.GetFile(strGhostScript).ShortPath
          strCommand = strGhostScript & " -q -dSAFER -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite"


            ' PDO: Passwort-Phrase, with Ghostscript only RC4 possible...
            If ((strUserPassword <> "") And (strOwnerPassword <> "")) Then
                strCommand = strCommand & " -sOwnerPassword=" & strOwnerPassword & " -sUserPassword=" & strUserPassword & " -dCompatibilityLevel=2.0"
            End If

          strCommand = strCommand & " -sOutputFile=" & Chr(34)

          strCommand = strCommand & strZielOrdner & "\"   'PDO: Danach kommt die Zieldatei und die einzelnen, anzubindenden Dateien.




          strTargetFile_without_Path = "Beratungsprotokoll_2018_Sammel.pdf"
          strFile_with_Path = strFile_for_pdf


               ' PDO: Gesamtcommand pt togehter ad executed
                strCommand = strCommand & strTargetFile_without_Path & Chr(34) & strFile_with_Path
                Debug.Print strCommand

                Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
                WshShell.Run strCommand, 0, True
                Set WshShell = Nothing


            fctPDO_Print_pdf_GhostScript = strZielOrdner & "\" & strTargetFile_without_Path


        ' Cleanup:
Err_Handler:

          Set fso = Nothing
          MsgBox "Done"


        End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for you response Nick it me help's me a lot.