# MS Access Password Protect PDF using Ghostscript - PDF document blank

Tags: vba, ms-access, pdf, ghostscript

this is my first post - be gentle!

I am looking to password protect PDF Reports from MS Access(version 2013)

I found [this question and answer on Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61937489/how-to-set-a-password-for-pdf-file-export) useful but have hit a snag

When the report is created it has all the necessary information but after calling the function (to password protect the PDF) the PDF report is blank. Name is the same and the PDF is password protected - but its blank!

The instruction being passed to Ghostscript is

```
-q -dSAFER -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOwnerPassword=170284 -sUserPassword=170284 -dCompatibilityLevel=2.0 -sOutputFile=D:\Data\ Report.pdf
```

the public function from the original (slightly modified) is

```
Public Function fctPDO_Print_pdf_GhostScript(strSourceFolder As String, strTargetFolder As String, strFile_for_pdf As String, Optional strUserPassword As String = "", Optional strOwnerPassword As String = "") As String

    ' http://www.herber.de/forum/archiv/1164to1168/1165503_Zusammenfuehren_von_PDF_Files.html#1165503
    ' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49953421/ghostscript-with-aes-256-password-protection-for-pdf-2-0-documents

    ' PDO: Prints a pdf (originally multi-pdf). Requires Ghostscript, and read/write rights.
    '      Existing files are overwritten without asking.
    '      Provide both passwords to lock. Ghostscript does rc4 , being comparatively unsafe.
    '

      On Error Resume Next

      Dim fso As Object, WshShell As Object
      Dim strCommand As String
      Dim strGhostScript As String

      Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    'Path to gswin32c.exe
      
        strGhostScript = "C:\Program Files (x86)\gs9.54.0\bin\gswin64c.exe"

    'Shell-command prepare
      
        strTargetFolder = fso.GetFolder(strTargetFolder).ShortPath
      
        strGhostScript = fso.GetFile(strGhostScript).ShortPath
   
    'PDO: Password-Phrase, with Ghostscript only RC4 possible...
    
            strCommand = strGhostScript & " -q -dSAFER -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOwnerPassword=" & strOwnerPassword
        
            strCommand = strCommand & " -sUserPassword=" & strUserPassword & " -dCompatibilityLevel=2.0"
             
            strCommand = strCommand & " -sOutputFile=" & strTargetFolder & "\" & strFile_for_pdf
        

    'Execute
                
            Debug.Print strCommand

            Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
            
                WshShell.Run strCommand, 0, True
            
            Set WshShell = Nothing


        fctPDO_Print_pdf_GhostScript = strTargetFolder & strFile_for_pdf


    ' Cleanup:
Err_Handler:

      Set fso = Nothing


    End Function
```

I have tried numerous things to debug including passing variation of the instruction but without much success - this is above my paygrade

I am hopeful someone can spot the error and assist

thanks in advance

Comment: Two things spring to mind. Your command line includes "-sOutputFile=D:\Data\ Report.pdf" If that's accurate then you have a problem, you have a space in the OutputFile specification and you haven't surrounded it with "". So that will treat the OutputFile as "D:\Data". I'm going to assume that's a typo in which case the second problem is that you haven't apparently specified an input file. Without that, nothing will be drawn. Because you have specified -dBATCH and -dNOPAUSE GS will exit and produce a blank file, just as you stated.

Comment: Also note; the input filename cannot be the same as the output filename, because that will corrupt the input file before Ghostscript reads it. The input and output files must be different.

Comment: @KenS thanks for the detailed reply.

Correct the space was a typo - sorry for that but thanks for picking it up

Thanks for the tip on the input file and for the different naming conventions

will give it a bash thanks

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Kens for the tips. Updated code which now works:

```
Public Function fctPDO_Print_pdf_GhostScript(strSourceFolder As String, strTargetFolder As String, strOriginalFile As String, strTargetFile As String, Optional strUserPassword As String = "", Optional strOwnerPassword As String = "") As String




    ' PDO: Prints a pdf (originally multi-pdf). Requires Ghostscript, and read/write rights.
    '      Existing files are overwritten without asking.
    '      Provide both passwords to lock. Ghostscript does rc4 , being comparatively unsafe.
    '

      On Error Resume Next

      Dim fso As Object, WshShell As Object
      Dim strCommand As String
      Dim strGhostScript As String

      Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    'Path to gswin32c.exe
      
        strGhostScript = "C:\Program Files (x86)\gs9.54.0\bin\gswin64c.exe"

    'Shell-command prepare
      
        strTargetFolder = fso.GetFolder(strTargetFolder).ShortPath
      
        strGhostScript = fso.GetFile(strGhostScript).ShortPath
   
    'PDO: Password-Phrase, with Ghostscript only RC4 possible...
    
            strCommand = strGhostScript & " -q -dSAFER -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOwnerPassword=" & strOwnerPassword
        
            strCommand = strCommand & " -sUserPassword=" & strUserPassword & " -dCompatibilityLevel=2.0"
             
            strCommand = strCommand & " -sOutputFile=" & strTargetFolder & "\" & strTargetFile

            strCommand = strCommand & " " & strSourceFolder & "\" & strOriginalFile

    'Execute
                
            Debug.Print strCommand

            Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
            
                WshShell.Run strCommand, 0, True
            
            Set WshShell = Nothing


        fctPDO_Print_pdf_GhostScript = strTargetFolder & strTargetFile


    ' Cleanup:

Err_Handler:

      Set fso = Nothing


    End Function
```